# Discrepancy between Classical Logic, Set Theory, Propositional Logic and Languages

Tags: semantics, cross-linguistic, theoretical-linguistics, philosophy-of-language, logic

In logic, "Or" strictly refers to logical disjuntion, while "And" strictly refers to logical conjuction.

But in common parlance, both can fill the role of Logical Disjunction

I understand that one should not use logic when talking to people because they may not understand you; but one needs to come clear and context does not always help. One should instead be redundant and repetitive.

When ambiquity arises (i.e. context does not help), how can you know what the person meant if you are unable to ask them to clarify it (e.g. it's written material, the person refuses to explain as they think logic is illogical and nonsense and that what they said was obvious, or any other reason)?

Comment: You can't know, under those circumstances. That's the point of ambiguity. Language is not logic, and it does not always work. Neither does logic. We just have to do the best we can.

Comment: @jlawler That is the whole point. Solving the problem that is ambiguity.

Comment: It's not a problem so much as it is a feature. Ambiguity can't be "solved", or even avoided, any more than entropy or gravity can. One can solve individual problems involving ambiguity; but there is no general solution. Understanding requires interpretation and presupposition by both speaker and addressee, and there is no correlation between them, except in individual cases.

Comment: "... but not concurrently both." as far as I can tell or means xor or and. of course that hinges on your definition of or. get it?

Comment: @vectory Or does not mean And. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction look at the Venn diagramms. My problem is that both Or and And can be used to mean Logical Disjunction. Each has a distinct function but both can fill the role of Logical Disjuntion.

Comment: have a look at paraconsistant logic for a start

Comment: @vectory But the problem is not inconsistency but rather ambiquity. I would be fine with anything as long as it is clear.

Comment: If it is ambiguous Maybe read past the Lede? By the way I find interesting the way you use "but": replace "not x but y" for simplicity's sake by "y and not x", which is the opposite of "y implies x"; you are merely saying it was not the case that ambiguity implied inconsistency. Fine. But might the revers be true?

Comment: @Vectory Y and not X is not the opposite of Y implies X. The first would be $y \land \lnot x$ while the latter would be  $y \implies x$ apples and oranges. One has nothing to do with the other. As for the "opposite" do you mean the inverse( $x \impliedby y$) or the negation $\lnotx$?

Comment: Could it be you just do not know boolean logic?

Comment: @Vectory I actually have studied Boolean Logic. The problem is that this Site does not give me access to math.

Comment: @vectory I do not think the requirement for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference) are met. y implies x is logically equivalent to not-Y or X. Did you mean the negation? In such case Y implies X is the logical equivalent of the negation of not-Y or X. As for the reverse were you asking if inconsistency implied or not ambiguity?

Comment: Yes, I'd call the negation of a truth value or formular its opposite. True is the opposite of false, in classical logic.

Comment: @vectory I would not know how to answer whether or not inconsistency implied or not ambiguity. I was an Economics student( now a graduate) so I got an A on Logic( Boolean Algebra) but really it was my only class with symbolism( Predicate logic is not as clear to me as Propositional logic). My intuition tells me that inconsistency does not imply ambiguity. Ambiguity and Inconsistency seem different concepts to me.

Comment: @vectory But Logical Equivalences mean that the two statements would be equivalent(the 2 premises or the 2 conclusions). Let's agree that clarity and consistency are the negations of ambiguity and inconsistency. If the following statement is true then what: Clear or Inconsistent or Ambiguous(Vague) or Consistent). What should follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different answers, depending on the environment.

In certain contexts (logical formulae, programming languages, legal documents, *Magic: the Gathering* cards), avoiding ambiguity is very important. So in these contexts, there'll be some external rule that tells you how to interpret ambiguities. For example, in *Magic: the Gathering* rules text, "or" is an exclusive disjunction; an inclusive disjunction will be written "choose one or more". In C++ source code, "or" is an inclusive disjunction; an exclusive disjunction will be written "xor". This will be laid out in some sort of authoritative reference document that you can consult when needed, such as the C++ Standard.

In all other environments, context should make it clear. If context doesn't make it clear, you can request more context (e.g. asking a waiter in a restaurant whether you can choose both sides, or only one). This falls under a branch of linguistics called *pragmatics*, and pragmaticists have come up with various formalisms for how people determine these things (most famously Grice's maxims).

Comment: Would man made clasifications; i.e from Authorities like some Academy, Society, University fail? Would adopting Logic in Languages fail?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos There's no central authority that decides how language is used. (Some authorities _try_, but they're never all that successful.) 99% of the time, the way language is used is the product of thousands of years of evolution; in English, distinguishing between inclusive and exclusive disjunction was never evolutionarily advantageous enough to show up and/or stick around.

Comment: And that is where law comes into play. Law is forceful, violent and external. Someone else imposes the rules. I was asking if it would pose a problem if the Authorities simply decided that for official documents, media and education purposes the language is like this with the penalty of nulification(of the document) expelling the teacher, fines for the media. if one goes against the rule.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos What would be the point? If the English-speaking community had a need for an inclusive/exclusive distinction in day-to-day life, one would have evolved.

Comment: Clarity. People in the Government, Academia, and Citizens are in need of clarity. Imagine a law that say or and does not make itself clear with its context. Both Students and Teachers/Professors benefit and the Government too.

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos As I said in my answer, laws and contracts already have specialized rules for removing ambiguity. If people actually found the distinction necessary in everyday life, they'd use it.

Comment: But it need be mandatory by extension external. Even if some(most) people find it necessary there is no need for those who did never think of Logic to use the distinction. If ones Teachers and Professors don't make themselves clear how would they do so?

Comment: @GeorgeNtoulos Your ideas of what English-speakers should find necessary don't seem to align with the 1.5 billion people who actually use the language. It's like saying that it's necessary for all fish to walk on land, getting confused when evolution hasn't gone that direction, and insisting on a massive engineering campaign to move all fish out of the water and onto land. If it were actually necessary, it would have happened through natural evolution. It hasn't.